# Inheritance and function calls parent and sub-class

Tags: php, inheritance

I encountered the following structure:

```
// parent class
class A 
{       
    public function myFunc1()
    {
        $this->myFunc2();
    }

    private function myFunc2() 
    {
        echo "called from class A";
    }
}

// sub-class
class B extends A
{ 
    private function myFunc2() 
    {
        echo "called from class B";
    }
}

$foo = new B();
$foo->myFunc1();
```

I expected, since there is no **myFunc1()** in class B, that the parent-function is called. This seems to be correct.

Now, to play it safe, I `var_dump` **$this** in **myFunc1()** and it shows, that this is an object from type B.

From my understanding, it should call **myFunc2()** from the Class B, but this isn't happening. It is calling the method from class A.

> called from class A

instead of

> called from class B

Yes, the functions are **private** and if I change it to **protected**, it works as expected. But private implies, that I have access to this function(s), when I'm in the specific context, doesn't it?

Comment: This code should fail. It is not possible to call a private method on an object. Only from the inside.

Comment: Private functions can only be accessed from within the class itself, children of that class only have access to public or protected functions of their parent

Comment: Think about the person writing the code. When she wrote `myFunc1`, she did so with the *knowledge* that there exists a private-to-that-class `myFunc2` and an *expectation* that this is the one to be called.

Comment: @Erik ur right, made a mistake there. the myFnc1() indeed is public. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

Private functions are **only** available within the class they are defined in, not in sub classes.

This means that your Object has two completely different functions, that happen to have the same name. Object B is aware of having one of them while Object A is only aware of having the other one. They do not interact in any way.

Since these functions are entirely private to the specific class they were defined in, there is no way to override them, or for any other class to call them.

If you need behavior that allows you to override how the class works, you'll have to use *protected* instead, which is designed specifically to be callable and changeable from extensions (and as such is a completely different beast all-together).

Answer (score 0):

`private` always belongs to the same class you can't inherit it. That's the reason why `myFunc1()` calls `myFunc2()` from class `A`. If you want to overwrite it you have to change the visibility to `protected`.